# Create combined source in pulseaudio

Tags: pulseaudio

I know it is possible to create a virtual combined sink in pulseaudio using the `module-combine-sink` module.

I wonder if there is something similar to create a virtual combined source. So a source that is a mix of all my other sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent in the [builtin modules](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/), but I can think of the following ways:

1) Configure the combined source in ALSA with the `dsnoop` plugin, then make it accessible for Pulseaudio with `module-alsa-source`

2) Use `module-null-sink` to create a "virtual" sink. For each source you want to combine, use an instance of `module-loopback` to route the source into the newly created virtual sink. Use the `.monitor` source of the virtual sink as combined source.

3) Look at the source code of `module-combine-sink`, use this to write your own `module-combine-source` module.

Comment: Windows has this built in, it's a little sad that to achieve the same in Linux is only for nerds.